# How to specify my database directory to apache tomcate

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

Basically I have a java servlet web app which uses apache tomcat v9.0 as it's server, The problem is that I need to save my database in file system and specify that if a user requested something like `localhost/db/image.png` apache should know that db is located at file system and reply back to user with image.

Thanks for all replies:)

Comment: Tried to understand the question by reading it twice, but it's still unclear what you are trying to achieve. *"to save my database in file system"* ? Do you mean *to save files* ?

Comment: no my database is already in `C:\db` but I just need to specify it somewhere where my web-app should understand that the database is at `C:\db` and that the file that has been request could be in `C:\db`, based on my googling i thing it could be done somewhere in my project `web.xml` or apache `/conf/server.xml` but I don't

Comment: How do you *serve* the content of the DB ?

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by serve the content of the DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat can be configured to read files from anywhere on disk and serve them on a specific URL. This configuration is completely separate to your application config – you could, if you wanted, just start Tomcat and have it serve static files from disk with no webapps running. The configuration is in Tomcat’s server.xml configuration file and looks like this (the bit that needs to be added is in red):

```
<Host appBase="webapps"
           autoDeploy="false" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true"
           xmlNamespaceAware="false" xmlValidation="false">
    ...
    <Context docBase="/home/stuff" path="/static" />

  </Host>
```

A `<Context>` element is added inside the `<Host>` element. Context has two attributes: docBase is the directory on disk that contains your static files and path is the URL that you want to serve the files on.

Make sure that Tomcat has access to read the files in docBase.

Using the example server.xml snippet above, if I had an image in /home/stuff called steve.jpg I would be able to access it via my local Tomcat instance using http://localhost:8080/static/steve.jpg.